# Cannot read Arabic letters after reading JSON file

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using this code to read a json.txt file which contains numbers and Arabic string :

```swift
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
        if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let person = jsonResult["Sheet1"] as? [Any] {          
            print(person)
        }
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

but the result of the Arabic string looks like that:

```
"Question" = "\U0648\U0644\U062f \U0627\U0644\U0646\U0628\U0649 \U0635\U0644\U0649 \U0627\U0644\U0644\U0647 \U0639\U0644\U064a\U0647 \U0648 \U0633\U0644\U0645 \U0641\U0649";
"answer 1" = "\U0627\U0644\U0645\U062f\U064a\U0646\U0647 \U0627\U0644\U0645\U0646\U0648\U0631\U0629";
```

Can anyone help me to solve it? 
Thanks

Comment: Is this the question "ولد النبى صلى الله عليه و سلم فى"? What you have there is Unicode codes but in swift they look a little different, instead of `\U0648` it is `\u{0648}` so the need to be converted.

Comment: What is the JSON input that generates this output (what are the exact contents of `json.txt`)? What kind of data structure would you like the parsed result to be in? (`[String: Any]` is a very difficult data structure to work with; what actual fields do you need?)

Answer (score 0):

you can set Encoding when you use String Format, so you can use below code:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
          let data = try String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "path"), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
          let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: .mutableLeaves)
          if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, Any>, let person = jsonResult["Sheet1"] as? [Any] {          
               print(person)
          }
       } catch {
           // handle error
       }
}
```

refer Link : [Apple Developer String Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414463-init)

Comment: The final result is a dictionary but it still needs to have decoding